# How to save click event in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to create a notification bell widget that pulls all articles that are tagged with the label `theBell`.

When a user clicks the icon that opens the list containing this articles, the notification count and the click event should be saved in local storage so that when the user refreshes the page the browser knows that those articles have "been read" (in my case the icon has been clicked).

My question is how can I capture that click event and save it to local storage?

```js
$.each(data.articles, function(index, item) {
  var style1 = '<li class = "eagle"><a href="' + item.html_url + '">' + item.title + '</a><span class = "eagleClose">x</span></li>'

  $('#notificationTab').append(style1);
  $('#notificationTab').each(function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("notificationTab").innerHTML;
    var res = str.replace(/null/g, ' ');
    document.getElementById("notificationTab").innerHTML = res;

    //count how many list items there are and display them in the tomato
    var tabLength = $('#notificationTab .eagle').length;
    $('.notificationCount').text(tabLength);

    //remove notificationCount when bell is clicked
    var removeTomato = $('.notificationTrigger').on('click', function() {
      $('.notificationCount').remove();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Use session storage instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @evolutionxbox why? localStorage is fine.

Comment: Here's the MDN guide which shows how to save and read localStorage data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Less "permanent" than local storage?

Comment: That's true, but doesn't seem relevant to what's being asked.

Comment: @evolutionbox If I use session storage then each time the user opens the browser the same count of notifications will appear. I want that after he clicks the icon  it should remain saved that he "read" those articles

Comment: @ORCos, you are already capturing the click event in the `.notificationTrigger` element. What is preventing you from saving data in localStorage at that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the relevant lines with these in your code and it should work:

```
//count how many list items there are and display them in the tomato
var tabLength = $('#notificationTab .eagle').length;
if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty('notificationCountViewed') && localStorage.getItem('notificationCountViewed')) {
     $('.notificationCount').text();
} else {
     $('.notificationCount').text(tabLength);
}
```

and also this:

```
//remove notificationCount when bell is clicked
var removeTomato = $('.notificationTrigger').on('click', function() {
  $('.notificationCount').remove();
  localStorage.setItem('notificationCountViewed', true);
});
```